# batch file to Open a server with password IE/fire fox with ip address

Tags: shell, powershell, batch-file, vbscript, ip

I wish  to open a server with IP address and user/password.
User enters in browser 192.168.0.3 then enter credentials sys/pass.
 i wrote a script for example --> start /p 192.168.0.3 sys/password
This does open a browser but does not enter password automatically.
What is the code? Can I write a command batch file for this purpose?
--aat45

Answer (score 0):

you can try

http://username:password@dummydomain.com as URI. Username and Password are submitted to the Webserver asking for Authetification.

Co.